# Installing new fonts for use with PDFlatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, installing

I have been looking around the web for guides on how to install a new font for LaTeX with PDFlatex. There are plenty of guides, but I have a hard time trying to follow them.

At the moment I have the following files and file structure:

```
-pwb(walbaum)
  -fonts
    -afm
      -abobe
        -walbaum
          <18x .afm files>
    -enc
      <empty>
    -map
      <1x .map file>
    -tfm
      -abobe
        -walbaum
          <60x .tfm files>
    -type1
      -abobe
        -walbaum
          <18x .pfb files>
    -vf
      -abobe
        -walbaum
          <30x .vf files>
  -tex
    -latex
      -abobe
        -walbaum
          <4x .fd files>
          <1x .sty file>
```

So what is the next steps to be able to use the font? Where should I put the files, etc? And will I be able to use it for math equations?

If you can explain it in a simple way, I would be glad.

Bonus info:
I am using TexMaker and PDFLatex on a Mac.

Comment: You find instructions in appendix B of this paper: http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100gregorio.pdf

Comment: Since you are using TeXLive, you will have to refresh your file database (`texhash`) and run `updmap`. But really: Use XeTeX or LuaTeX. Both do microtype, LuaTeX more so.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, wouldn't it be better to use `updmap-sys` if it is a single user system?

Comment: @daleif: Probably. :-)

Comment: @daleif Better to use it if it is a single user system; ***essential*** if it is a multi user system. (Unless installing the font in your personal tree but that is not recommended unless you don't have permission to do anything else. In which case no need to update the database either.)

Answer (score 1):

Essentielly you're missing a `pwb.map` file which describes the correspondence between the virtual fonts and the actual, type 1 fonts, so that pdflatex or dvips can use them. You install it in `your_local_texmf\ fonts\map`\adobe` (not abobe!). That done:

1. Add to your `local` `updmap.cfg` this line: `Map pwb.map`
2. Run `texhash` (TeXLive or MacTeX) or `Refresh FNBD` (MiKTeX)
3. Run `initexmf --mkmaps` to refresh the databases of type 1 fonts

You can see more details in  the excellent `Font Installation Guide`

Comment: I have a problem with no.3 in your procedure. When I run the command `initexmf --mkmaps` I get the following error: `-bash: initexmf: command not found`.

Comment: Oh! I gave the procedure for MiKTeX. For TeX Live and MacTeX, run (+ sudo if you're not under Windows) `updmap-sys --enable Map=pwb.map, then run `texhash``.

Comment: It seems like the terminal commands worked. However, when I try to use the font, I end up with this warning: `Font shape `T1/pwb/m/n' undefined`.

I am trying to load the font with `\usefont{T1}{pwb}{m}{n}\selectfont`

Any ideas of what is wrong?

Comment: Mac OS X - Mavericks

Comment: Sudo? Do you have a t1pwb.fd file, and the relevant .vf files?

Comment: I used `sudo` before the commands. With regard to the `t1pwb.fd` file, I have 4 different types of them: `t1pwbj.fd, t1pwbx.fd, ts1pwbj.fd` and `ts1pwbx.fd`. They are located in `texlive -> texmf-local -> tex -> latex -> walbaum`. I also have a bunch (30) of .vf files. They are called `pwbb8c.vf` (or something similar) and are located in `texlive -> texmf-local -> fonts -> vf -> walbaum`

Comment: Ok, I will leave it for now.. It seems to work (no warnings or error) when I use `\usefont{T1}{pwbj}{m}{n}\selectfont` or `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` `\fontfamily{pwbj}\selectfont`, but the font has not changed. Now it is just the default LaTeX font.

Comment: You should check if they're mentioned in `dvips.map`, `pdftex.map` and the like. It's thoses files that are used to load the real fonts. Also run maketexlsr and updmap-sys in verbose mode  (--verbose) to see what really happens.

Comment: Generally, I think you need to update the filename database *before* you run `updmap-sys` else it won't find the map file. But I'm not sure - I've never done it the other way. @Christoffer Where did you add the map line? That is, which file? Try `updmap-sys --enable Map=pwb.map` - this is generally easier for a single file addition as you don't need to worry about which file to edit. Also, if the directory `/Users/YourUserName/.texliveYYYY` exists where YYYY is the year of the version you are using, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know of the fontspec package? According to the [documentation](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) it "allows users of either XeTeX or LuaTeX to load OpenType fonts in a LaTeX document. No font installation is necessary, and font features can be selected and used as desired throughout the document."

I use it with documents typeset using pdflatex on Mac, simply putting

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainsfont{Georgia}
```

to use Georgia, which is installed as a system font.

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use the fontspec package, is that is not is compatible with the microtype package, which I use.

Comment: @GeertF that doesn't work with PDFLaTeX, only with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Christoffer `microtype` supports most of it functionality with LuaLaTeX.